# Unable to load DLL or of its dependencies Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, dllimport

The main project is DotNet Core Web API and ModelView project that is used by the main project. The ModelView project uses a C++ DLL file. When I run the main project in VS and local IIS, it works. When I push the project to Azure Web App or VM, it complains from the DLL file. It says that the file is unable to load or one of its dependencies. The error shows that it cannot find the DLL file in the local path where my VS resides. Is the issue with DLL or the path is not updated when the project is pushed remotely?  Why the ModelView project is still pointing to the local path where my VS project is located?

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'RateModule_PAMI.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

at App.Application.Features.GetHandler.Handle(GetQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\UserName\Source\Repos\Service\App.Application\Features\Q\Queries\Module\GetHandler.cs:line 55

Why is still pointing to my local VS project?

Comment: Can you share your sample code for us without any sensitive info, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste `RateModule_PAMI.dll` to scm site, then try. Check if your webapp is running normally. According to my understanding, it should not be possible, but I still recommend you to try it.

If you can, then you can just include that dll file when publishing.

If not, it should be normal, because the webapp runs in a sandbox environment and we cannot use third-party `.dll` files.

## Tips

If possible, can you create a sample demo for me without any sensitive info and business code. Let us check it.